# footnote issue in tables and cells

Tags: tables, footnotes

There are two problems with footnotes in a table cell.

1- Although the superscript number is placed above the word, but the detail is not shown at the bottom on page.

2- I don't want to use numbering style. I want to put a symbol `*` for some word and all of them have one description which I want to write in the bottom of the page.

How can I fix the following code?

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\title{my title} 
\maketitle
\section{Section 1}
Table~\ref{my-label} shows 
  \begin{table} 
  \centering    
  \caption{the caption}
  \label{my-label}
  \begin{tabular}{>{\centering}p{1.5cm}|>{\centering}p{1.5cm} }
    Year  & Architecture
    \tabularnewline
    \hline
     first column &     second column 
    \tabularnewline
     A            &     WORD\footnote{explanation}
    \tabularnewline
     B            &     WORD\footnote{explanation}
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: please, provide mwe!

Comment: I have updated the code. I was easy to add some begin and end document though...

Comment: well, than you have easy task ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure to have fully understood what you want, but the `tablefootnote` package can help. Does this code yield more or less what you want?

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\title{my title}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\leavevmode
\vfill
%\vspace*{30\baselineskip}
\section{Section 1}
Table~\ref{my-label}
 shows
  \begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
  \caption{the caption}
\label{my-label}
  \begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}}%{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}}
    Year & Architecture
    \tabularnewline
    \hline
     first column & second column
    \tabularnewline
     A & WORD\tablefootnote{explanation}
    \tabularnewline
     B & WORD\footnotemark[\value{footnote}]
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK. Right now, `tlmgr install tablefootenote` stuck and nothing is shown in the console. I think there is a problem with network. Anyway... Your method answers my first question. For the second question, I actually want to put `*` for both WORD. You used two symbols which is not what I am looking for. Think that they have identical explanation in the footnote.

Comment: Do you mean both should refer to the same footnote?

Comment: Yes. That is right.

Comment: It's easy. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: BTW, I get `LaTeX Error: File `tablefootnote.sty' not found` and the CTAN archive at https://ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote?lang=en doesn't contain .sty. Any idea?

Comment: Is your TeX Live installation up-to-date?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92091/discussion-between-bernard-and-mahmood).

Comment: OK. I finally managed to install the packages. Thanks for the solution. It is working.

Comment: All's well that ends well! I saw the CTAN page you reffered o, and indeed there's only a .dtx. Compiling this .dtx  produces the .sty file. However, in `https://ctan.org/tex-archive/install/macros/latex/contrib`, you find a `tablefootnote.tds.zip` file, ready to install: you only have to unzip it at your local TeX root.